# How to have a global constant accessible in all packages in golang?

Tags: go

I have a constant defined within a package in golang as such:

```
package services

const (
   Source = "local"
)
```

I would like to make this constant accessible by other packages without having to import the package into my other module. How can I go about that?

Comment: Why don't you want to import  `services`?

Comment: You can't. You have to import the package with constants.

Comment: @LutzHorn I can import services. But the services package is extremely big and I would like to use a single constant defined within services for a special use case. Ideally I would extract constants into it's separate module, bur for now, I was wondering if golang has any native support for global constants.

Comment: If you don't use the other parts of the imported package, the Go compiler should take care not include all of it into the generated binary.

Comment: You can´t do that, I recomend you instead doing that, pass the constant as parameter in your functions, while the constant live in the main package

Answer (score 21):

You cannot refer to services.Source without importing services.

However, you can avoid the dependency by creating a new constant in another package that happens to have the same value, and verify that with a test. That is, your test imports services, but your production code does not. The stdlib does this here and there to avoid a few dependencies.

```
// services.go
package services

const Source = "local"

// foo.go
package foo

const Source = "local"

// foo_test.go
package foo

import (
    "services"
    "testing"
)

func TestSource(t *testing.T) {
    if Source != services.Source {
        t.Error("Source != services.Source")
    }
}
```